# Flask server side implemetation for certificate based Auth

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to implement server side code to authenticate the client using certificate and Authorize based on the Groups associated in certificate.

The client side code goes like this:

```
import json
import requests
    
clientCrt = "cc.crt"
clientKey = "ck.key"
url = "https://example.com/api"
payload = { "someId": "myID" }
certServer = 'cs.crt'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), verify=certServer, 
                  headers=headers, cert=(clientCrt, clientKey))
print(r.status_code)
print(r.json())
```

I want to have a corresponding server side implementation specifically to check whether request should be honoured based on the *clientCrt*

Can someone share how i can access the clientCrt on server side and extract the fields of certificate.

Note: I am not looking for mutual TLS Auth, I am interested in Service Authentication and Authorization

Comment: You write you are not interested in mutual TLS authentication, but you want to authenticate the client. Do you mean that you want to authenticate only the client and not the server? To authenticate traffic between different services and not external clients?

Comment: The client and the server are both in a controlled infrastructure. So, SSL is not much of an issue. However, who is the user accessing the service, what is the group that the user belongs to and hence whether they are authorized to use the endpoint or not is the main objective here.

Answer (score 0):

Mutual TLS is not configured on a default wsgi serving connection object. This needs to be configured. See this page for more details - https://www.ajg.id.au/2018/01/01/mutual-tls-with-python-flask-and-werkzeug/. Once you have the connection object handy, you can use request.environ['peercert'].get_subject() to get the details of the client cert.

Better way to handle this is by delegating it to Gunicorn or nginx proxy. See https://eugene.kovalev.systems/posts/flask-client-side-tls-authentication/ for more examples

Comment: Unfortunately the second link seems to be dead (and the first link is currently timing out for me...)